# Как оптимизировать мой запрос к mongodb с помощью dataloader

Tags: node.js, mongodb

У меня стоит задача: Оптимизировать выполнение основного скрипта сокращателя ссылок, а именно переход по короткой ссылке и перенаправление на исходную.
Я решил попробовать сделать это при помощи dataloader, прочитал статьи на эту тему, посмотрел видео, но в них были слишком сложные запросы к бд, в моём же случае всё элементарно и я не особо понимаю, как тут можно лаконично воспользоваться dataloader, если вообще есть смысл это делать, буду благодарен любой помощи с реализацией dataloader или подсказкам относительно общего решения моей задачи...
Думаю попробовать memcached

```js
router.get('/:shortUrl', async (req, res) => {
  await Url.findOne({shortUrl: req.params.shortUrl}, async (err, obj) => {
    obj.counter = parseInt(++obj.counter);
    await obj.save();
    res.redirect(obj.url);
  });
});
```

```js
router.get('/:shortUrl', async (req, res) => {
  const dbItem = await Url.findOne({shortUrl: req.params.shortUrl});
  dbItem.counter = parseInt(++dbItem.counter);
  res.redirect(dbItem.url);
  dbItem.save();
});
```

Comment: а что в нем оптимизировать? В запросе  всего 1 параметр передается

Comment: `await obj.save();` перенести после `res.redirect(obj.url);` и убрать `await`. Так счетчик будет "тикать" уже после отправки ответа в браузер. Больше оптимизировать тут нечего.

Comment: @Дмытрык  Я немного код подправил. Мне нужно было провести нагрузочное тестирование основного действия, а именно перенаправление на длинную ссылку, а затем оптимизировать, лично я вижу метод оптимизации кешированием, что-то вроде: пользователь обращается в 1 раз к бд, а дальнейшие запросы по такой же короткой ссылке будут идти уже не в бд, а в кеш сервера

Comment: @Total Pusher Я немного код подправил. Мне нужно было провести нагрузочное тестирование основного действия, а именно перенаправление на длинную ссылку, а затем оптимизировать, лично я вижу метод оптимизации кешированием, что-то вроде: пользователь обращается в 1 раз к бд, а дальнейшие запросы по такой же короткой ссылке будут идти уже не в бд, а в кеш сервера

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Про текущий код

В исходном коде "бутылочным горлышком" являлась конструкция

```
await obj.save();
res.redirect(obj.url);
```

Сначала ждем увеличение счетчика, потом отдаем response. Нужно поменять порядок:

```
res.redirect(obj.url);
obj.save();
```

Теперь ответ отправляется сразу, и мы асинхронно увеличиваем счетчик. Может быть, достаточно было бы убрать `await` и не менять порядок строк, но я предполагаю, что так в очередь библиотеки `libuv` отправка HTTP-ответа станет первой и выполнится раньше.

Теперь мне не нравится эта конструкция:

```
dbItem.counter = parseInt(++dbItem.counter);
```

Допустим, значение счетчика 100. Одновременно пришли два запроса. В одном посчиталось 101 и в другом 101. Оба сохранили 101, что неверно. В Mongo именно для этой цели есть [$inc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/), получится так:

```
Url.update(
   { shortUrl: req.params.shortUrl },
   { $inc: { counter: 1 } }
);
```

Теперь счетчик будет считать верно.

### Про нагрузку

Не знаю, на какую нагрузку вы рассчитываете. Для 100 запросов в сек будет одна стратегия, а для 10 000 тыс - другая. И тут дело не в коде, а уже в архитектуре. А для проверки нужно нагрузочное тестирование, для этого есть много инструментов, в простом случае можно использовать [Apache ab](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/programs/ab.html).

У вас, похоже, небольшой проект.

В таком случае я бы поставил Nginx как реверс-прокси и настроил на нем кеширование. Вот [мой конфиг](https://github.com/dbfun/nginx-cached-proxy/blob/master/nginx/proxy.conf), который нужно доработать под себя: включить опцию `proxy_cache_background_update on` и другие.

Тут есть такой интересный момент: допустим, кеша нет (протух, либо еще не создался) и приходит 1000 запросов. Можно отправить всю тысячу на бек, и даже если на беке есть мемкеш, в нем так же может не быть данных. И бек будет 1000 раз получать данные из Монги и 1000 раз сохранять их в мемкеше. Nginx же умеет обрабатывать такую ситуацию: он пошлет один запрос на бек, а 999 клиентов поставит на "паузу". Когда данные придут, он разошлет их всей 1000. Для этого нужно включить [proxy_cache_lock](https://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_cache_lock).

Вообще, посмотрите все опции Nginx, содержащие слово "cache".

Плюсы и минусы этого способа:

- может держать очень высокую нагрузку, по сути будет чтение из файлов, которые также кешируются в памяти
- счетчик не будет увеличиваться

**Если счетчик важен, то:**

- NodeJS использует только одно ядро CPU => посмотрите как организовать кластер, задействуя все доступные ядра
- получение данных с Mongodb => монго также можно развернуть как кластер (см "Шардинг"), имеет смысл если очень много данных

**Кеширование на беке:**

- мемкеш => несколько инстансов NodeJS, обслуживающие запросы, могут считать общие данные
- сделать просто переменную `lastUri = { "uri_1" => "https://ya.ru", ... }`, она будет в памяти, но доступна только для одного инстанса, и ее нужно чистить

**Обновление счетчика:**

Можно "копить" новые значения в том же мемкеше, и один раз в минуту обновлять. Да, что-то можно потерять.